# Serialize multiple objects without ModelViewSet

Tags: python, django

I have `models` and `serializer` and `views` with `rest framework`

However I want to make view not by `viewsets.ModelViewSet` by my original one `get_by`

but in `ModelViewSet`

serializer could be set easily

```
serializer_class = MyTextSerializer
```

serializer.py

```
class MyTextSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    my_status = serializers.SerializerMethodField()    
    class Meta:
        model = MyText
        fields = ('id','text','created_at','pub_date')  
    def get_my_status(self,obj):
        res = ["mystatus"]
        return res
```

normal `ModelViewSet` view but I don't want to use this now.

```
class MyTextViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyText.objects.all().order_by('created_at')
    serializer_class = MyTextSerializer ## serializer works here.
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
```

in views.py I wanto use this.

```
@api_view(['POST', 'GET'])
def get_by(request):
    ts = MyTexts.objects.all().order_by('id')[0:10]
    serializer = MyTextSerializer(ts[0]) ## it works, but I want to serialize multiple items `ts`
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

However I have no idea how to pass the multiple queryset to Serializer as `ModelViewSet` dose.

Does anyone help??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`many=True`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-multiple-objects) as,

```
serializer = MyTextSerializer(ts, many=True)
```